# LESS CSS define variables when another variable is true

Tags: css, less

I've used guard expressions elsewhere in my CSS to achieve IF statements in LESS, however these don't work for me when trying to declare variables like so...

```
@neutral: false;
@warm: true;

when (@neutral = true) {
    @green: #91C95B;
    @red: #F15647;
    etc...
}
when (@warm = true) {
    @green: #91AD3C;
    @red: #BF2A23;
    etc...
}
```

This is an example of how I would like to be able to use that variable

```
h1 {
    color:@green;
}
```

This is how I would expect it to compile down to CSS

```
h1 {
    color: #91AD3C;
}
```

Is this possible with LESS or would I need to modify my code to use mixin guards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Guarded Mixins` like this :

```
@neutral: false;
@warm: true;

.color() when (@neutral) {
    @green: #91C95B;
}
.color() when (@warm) {
    @green: #91AD3C;
}
.color();


h1 {
    color:@green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I think the LESS documentation could do with some clarification as it isn't clear regarding this usage of mixin guards.

Comment: > I think the LESS documentation could do with some clarification - The documention is actually quite detailed on the guards stuff ([Mixin Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature), [CSS Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature)). I guess what you're missing is actually variable scope info which is indeed not quite documented (except two minor sections: [Scope](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope), [Mixins as Functions](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature)).